# Determine the stroke width of a UIFont

Tags: ios, cgcontext, uifont, typography, uifontdescriptor

I want to draw glyph like graphical elements (using a `CGContextRef`) that match the stroke width of a `UIFont` instance so that they combine with it harmoniously, even as the font size is varied.

So, given a `UIFont`, or a `UIFontDescriptor`, is there a reasonably robust mechanism under iOS to determine the font's stroke width?

Specifically, I only need to do this for [Helvetica Neue](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/00/Helvetica_Neue_typeface_weights.svg/2000px-Helvetica_Neue_typeface_weights.svg.png). However, it would be nice, interesting and jolly satisfying, to have a general solution.

---

With numerous fonts, the stroke width varies even within individual glyphs ([Zapfino](http://frankie.bz/blog/tips-and-tricks/95-alternatives-to-12-classic-fonts/), for example). In such cases, asking for a stroke width wouldn't make a lot of sense. A null result from a query would be entirely reasonable response.

In fact, I think even with Helvetica Neue, the stroke width may not be uniform within glyphs. Some robust and reasonable approximation would be great, though. The width used by the lowercase l, say. Or something.